# Strange wp admin edit buttons issue

Tags: wp-admin

I'm having an issue from within wp admin.  Whenever I click on an edit button the popup window that usually appears doesn't.

Examples:-

1. Editing a permalink from with a normal page.

[image: wp page permalink edit window]

2. Editing a advanced custom fields link field (see below from another site)

[image: acf link popup window]

3. Editing Yoast SEO plugin setup wizard

As you can read from the list it seems to be a wp problem and not a specific plugin.

I tried updating all plugins & core (to the latest versions), deactivating all plugins (one at a time), flushing the permalinks but nothing seems to work.

Anyone have an idea what is causing the problem and/or how I can fix it?

Comment: Just because the issue occurs in multiple places doesn't mean that the cause is WordPress. WordPress has not shipped a bug where it doesn't work. A plugin is more than likely causing the issue in all these places. Try the normal troubleshooting steps of deactivating plugins until it works, then you'll find the culprit.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @JacobPeattie but I have already performed this task.  I even wrote about it in my question :)

Comment: What do you mean by "popup window that usually appears"?

Comment: @gael I've added some screenshots (from another site) to show you what I mean

Comment: Ok, did you check for Console Errors in your browser?

Comment: @gael Great shout!  A console error pointed me in the direction of a js script loading in the wrong order.  Now my problem is solved.  Thank you for the tip!